# Can we do a regression for statistically insignificant data?

Tags: regression

I'm testing the sensitivity of different factors on the benefits of precision irrigation. The change in the inputs is changing the output but not significantly.
How is it possible to do a regression for these factors?

Comment: If this means your inputs and outputs are not correlated, you can not perform a regression.

Comment: What do you mean by 'significantly'?  If you mean changes in the input change the output 'by a small amount' then you can certainly run the regression.  You may get a larger standard error than you would like (and hence a larger p-value) depending on how much data you have and how much noise there is, but you can definitely do it.  There is a difference between 'statistically significant' and 'significant' as in a large regression coefficient.  Hope that helps...

Comment: Of course. How would you for instance find out that a variable is not 'statistically significant' if not by regression?

Comment: what if the variables are not completely dependent? shall we do a step wise regression?!

Comment: Nope. Look up stepwise regression before performing it (as with any analysis you don't understand), and read my answer. You don't need your variables to be completely dependent or completely independent to perform regression analysis. Its purpose is to estimate the degree of dependency, so its functionality *can't* depend on this.

Answer (score 3):

The basic function of regression analyses is to estimate the strength of predictive associations between predictor (independent) variables and target (dependent) variables, usually both in terms of individual predictors and the total set of predictors (when there is more than one, as you've implied is relevant to your question's motivation). Much like a bivariate correlation, these predictive associations are essentially matters of effect size first, and can only become matters of significance by asking a question about these estimates, such as, "Do I think that more than 5% of all the other random samples like mine could exhibit predictive associations as strong or stronger than the one present in my sample, yet in fact be drawn from a population in which there is no association overall?" This is the question a typical null hypothesis significance test aims to answer about a regression model or regression coefficient. It is a question about an association that doesn't inherently need to involve matters of significance; one can ask it about any point estimate of a regression coefficient regardless of what data is used in producing the estimate, let alone whether that estimate is different from zero at all.

@ExpectoPatronum's comment is false. Even the correlation of completely uncorrelated data can be calculated ($r = 0$). If someone sets out to test "the significance" of this correlation, one probably means to test the two-tailed significance of its difference from zero. Since $r = 0, t_{(N-2)} = 0, p = 1$, but this doesn't stop one from using the relevant formulas to "calculate" these results.  The same is true in linear regression. If all $\beta = 0$, then the model's $R^2 = 0$, the omnibus $F_{(N-k-1)} = 0, p =1$, and all individual $t_{(N-k-1)}=0, p=1$. Totally "insignificant" results in the common sense of being identical to zero, but still a completely possible result of the analysis. If this result weren't a possible outcome of any significance test, one couldn't really claim to be falsifying the typical null hypothesis with it. Regardless, the significance tests aren't really necessary to consider when estimating $\beta$ or $R^2$, which are the only definitional products of bare-bones regression analysis. One can consider the significance of one's estimates of these parameters after calculating them if desired, but the estimation process is the more basic statistical procedure that has to precede the usual significance question, not the other way around.

To be fair, a more interesting interpretation of "significance" in this question might be with respect to a prior significance test of the data's distributional normality or homoscedasticity, but I assume these aren't the significance tests you have in mind. You seem to be worried about the weakness or uncertainty of causal(?) associations. At no extreme do these qualities of data utterly preclude regression analysis; they do not affect one's basic ability to perform the analysis at all. The validity of regression results is a different matter, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can "do" a regression between any dependent (or output) variables and any independent (or input) variables. Different sorts of regression make different assumptions about the data (but often these are about the error term, as estimated by the residuals from the model).

You cannot know if the regression is significant without doing it.

Beyond that, it is hard to say, since you haven't told us anything about the data. What is your output variable? What is/are your input variable(s)? How were they collected? What is your sample size? etc.

You may find my post [How to Ask a Statistics Question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) helpful in formulating your question.

Comment: it's not a survey. I've just calculated the benefits of an irrigation system and tried to change the inputs by a certain range  to observe how the benefits would change therefore my output is Y=benefits and I have about 50 repetitions (changing 8 inpupts 6 times)